# How to make the Win32 APP Background Transparent?

Tags: c++

How to make the Win32 APP Background Transparent?
in C++ i want to make the background of the program to look like the desktop picture.

Answer (score 3):

Give it the [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx) extended window style, and handle WM_ERASEBKGND message by doing nothing.

This will make the transparent parts of your window transparent to mouse messages also, if you don't want that, then handle the WM_NCHITTEST message and return HTCLIENT rather than HTTRANSPARENT.

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
   {
   lRet = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
   if (HTTRANSPARENT == lRet)
      lRet = HTCLIENT;
   }
```

Comment: I think that only works for child windows.  WS_EX_LAYERED is a better mousetrap for top-level windows.